# Elastic Beanstalk Single instance SSL nginx puma connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx

Hello Helpful overflowers,

I am trying to deploy a rails app to elastic beanstalk as a single instance, using the nginx, puma, and ruby container. All is well, except I am having a bit of trouble getting the servers configured right. This is my first non-heroku deploy using this stack, so I know next to nothing about nginx and puma, although I am eager to learn. Help would be appreciated.

The problem is that I can access the site fine with my custom domain name:

http://myapp.com -> redirects correctly to https://www.myapp.com

https://www.myapp.com -> works like a champ

but if I type https://myapp.com -> connection refused

I have used the bucket trick to redirect the top level domain to www. This involves setting the A record for myapp.com to be an S3 bucket, which redirects to the www subdomain.

I am trying to use SSL cert. I have more or less copy and pasted the the nginx config from their docs from [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSLRuby.SingleInstance.html) replacing the certificates and relevant parts with my own as needed.

Puma is bound: 
puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:443' I don't know if that is correct, but someone on the internet said that somewhere.

the production environment file is set to force_ssl: true

Please offer any advice, or let me know any additional information that would be required to figure out the problem. I am really kinda feeling my way around in the dark here.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?